# Can you pass a Stream object to a method to write to that specific stream?

Tags: c#, networking, stream, client

I currently have a server and two clients which communicate with it. Each time a client connects to the server, I store the `Stream` instance as a value and a client ID as a key in a concurrent dictionary.

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, NetworkStream> pumpIDAndStream = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, NetworkStream>();

//then later in the program

pumpIDAndStream.AddOrUpdate(clientID.ToString(), stream, (k, v) => stream);
```

I then use this method to try and send a message to a specific client instance based on the stream object stored in the dictionary:

```
private void proceedPump(byte[] b_recievedLine)
{

    string s_messageBody = DESDecrypt(b_recievedLine, DCSP);
    string[] delim = { " " };
    string[] strings = s_messageBody.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


    NetworkStream pumpStream = pumpIDAndStream[(strings[0])]; //strings[0] is the specific client ID
    byte[] empty = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(""); 

    pumpStream.Write(messageFormatting(empty, 0x14, DCSP), 0, empty.Length);
    pumpStream.Flush();

}
```

After debugging, it does get to the `pumpStream.Flush();` but nothing is picked up on the specific client. Any pointers?

Comment: @CharlesMager Empty is just the message body, the messageformatting method returns a byte array prefixed with a header with a message type (0x14). Empty is just empty because I dont want to deal with passing shared keys for decryption, the real thing is sending the 0x14 byte in the header.

Comment: you're still using its length as the count argument - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not writing anything.

`empty` is an empty array, and your call to `Write` uses its length (`0`) as the number of bytes to be written (see [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write(v=vs.100).aspx) - you're specifying `count` as `0`).

You probably want to do something like this:

```
var bytesToWrite = messageFormatting(empty, 0x14, DCSP);
pumpStream.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
```

Comment: I take back my comment. Well spotted! this looks exactly what the issue is and exactly how to fix it.